# php getting all values of a specific column from an array

Tags: php

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [No.,"Ticker","Company"] => 
                        1,"A","Agilent Technologies Inc." ) 
        [1] => Array ( [No.,"Ticker","Company" ] => 
                        2,"AA","Alcoa, Inc.") 
      )
```

This is the output when i type print_r($arrayOne);
What can I do so I can only get the Company column i.e. Agilent Technologies Inc, and Alocoa, Inc.

I tried echo $arrayOne['Company'] and $arrayOne[0]['Company'] but it just outputted 'Array'.

Comment: is it because array within an array??

Comment: No, it is because there's no `Company` key in either of those arrays.

Comment: How the heck did you even construct this type of array? Never seen that before.

Comment: Not sure I've seen a `print_r` output like that before

Comment: $csvArr = csv_to_array(file_get_contents('companies.csv')); Then, i did print_r($csvArr);

Comment: @ealeon Why didn't you use [fgetcsv](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php) then? )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you have is an outer array with two sub-arrays, each of which has only one value. Its key is the description of the 3 columns, and its value is the CSV value.  If you have PHP 5.3, use [`str_getcsv()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-getcsv.php) to parse it and return the third column

```
// Loop over the outer array
foreach ($arrayOne as  $subarr) {
  // Loop over the sub-arrays (though your sample only has one value each)
  // could also use array_pop()
  foreach ($subarr as $key => $csvstring) {
    // $csvstring holds the CSV value like  '1,"A","Agilent Technologies Inc."'
    // Parse it with str_getcsv()
    $cols = str_getcsv($csvstring);
    // Company name is the 3rd value, key [2]
    echo $cols[2] . "\n";
  }
}
```

For example with the input:

```
$arrayOne = array(
  array('No.,"Ticker","Company"' => '1,"A","Agilent Technologies Inc."' ), 
  array('No.,"Ticker","Company"'  => '2,"AA","Alcoa, Inc."') 
);
// The above loop prints:
Agilent Technologies Inc.
Alcoa, Inc.
```

Comment: It's definitely the right way to go (+1), still I wonder why this statement - `echo $arrayOne[0]['Company']` - resulted in `Array` (as mentioned in the question).

Comment: so $csv = file_get_contents('finviz.csv'); ?

Comment: @ealeon No, file_get_contents() isn't needed.  `$csv` is the loop iteration, which is an array value. I'll change it above because it isn't clear.  Each of those is a subarray from `$arrayOne`.

Answer (score 0):

Your array should be like this:

```
$arrayOne = array(array('no' => 1, 'ticker' => 'A', 'company' => 'Agilent Technologies Inc.'),
                  array('no' => 2, 'ticker' => 'AA', 'company' => 'Alcoa Inc.'));

echo $array[0]['company']; // will print Agilent Technologies
```